# How to Track Clicks in an IFrame with Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, google-analytics, tracking

I'd like to track outbound clicks within an iframe on my self-hosted Wordpress site. I already use Google Analytics to track inbound visitors (GA code in the header), but I'd like to know which/how many of those visitors click on links within the iframe on each of my pages.  For the record, the iframe does come from an external advertiser.

This is the iframe code I was given (using sample names in place of real ones):

```
<iframe src="http://www.advertisersite123.com//widget.html?width=510&height=950&product=2" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="510" height="950"></iframe>
```

This line of code is currently pasted on single.php, making a table of links appear on every single post at the bottom of the page.

I'd like to know how many clicks (just clicks in general is fine, don't need to know where they go) are occurring in this iframe.  Ideally broken down by each individual URL on my website so I can determine which URLs are more successful in generating clicks within the iframe.

And if possible, I'd like to create a funnel that tells me which visitors to my website (by source) exit via clicks in the iframe.

Is any of this possible?  And if so, what code do I add to the page?

Thank you for any and all assistance, it is appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

What you are asking for is not easily done. In general, you cannot have javascript on the parent page that can hook into events on the iframed page if it is not hosted on the same domain.  Same thing for the iframe page trying to tap into the parent page's DOM. This is called cross-site scripting (XSS), which goes against the same domain origin policy.

At a minimum, the easiest thing to do would be to put the GA code on the iframed page. But that's probably not something you can do (though it couldn't hurt to ask the vendor).

But some vendors (usually social media vendors such as Facebook, Google and Twitter) will have their widgets that output an iframe w/ info.  They will set their server to allow for cross-domain scripting, which would allow you to tap into the iframe's DOM.  Usually though they provide an API along with the widget that makes it easier to hook into relevant events (like share events), so that you don't have to do (much) coding yourself.

Basically long story short, there's no way for you to track it without the person in charge of the iframe domain getting involved.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for clearing that up for me.  So there's not even a way to know something as "simple" as how many of your visitors exit via the iframe?  Or something similar to backdoor the analytics and get a rough estimate?

Comment: No there is not, unless you do something on the iframe page itself. Understand that it is a security measure that a page should not have visibility into the iframe and visa versa, when it's a different domain. All kinds of crazy could ensue if that were allowed. I feel ya; this is a huge stumbling block with analytics vs. 3rd party vendor stuff being iframed onto pages :( but it is what it is

Comment: Since the security policy will very likely never go away, the only option is to work with the vendor to implement tracking on their iframe content, or else come up with a different system for including the info on the page. Perhaps the vendor offers a server-side API that will let you retrieve the content server-side and then you can output the content on the parent page as if it's your own content.  Then you'd be able to attach GA stuff to it easy enough.  You'd be surprised how often 3rd party vendors are willing to work with this sort of thing

Comment: 3rd party vendor being able to offer people an API for analytics is a great selling point for them. I've personally worked with a ton of random providers to establish this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the added information and advice.  Looks like I'll have to speak with the advertiser to see what they can do for me, seeing that tracking is completely null at the moment.  You'd think these companies would care about things like this...

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for something similar and came across this. This jQuery [Plugin](https://github.com/finalclap/iframeTracker-jquery) lets you track an Iframe.

Comment: This is great but doesn't work for mobile, since it relies on mouse position.

Answer (score 1):

Tried events?

If the click is out of iframe:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', eventCategory, eventAtion, eventLabel]);
```

If the click is inside the iframe you should use:

```
window.parent._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', eventCategory, eventAtion, eventLabel]);
```

Comment: This is only plausible if you have control over both the host website and the iframe content website. In the OP's case this won't work

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but anyways it could be helpful, specially since this is a solution using GA4, with Universal Analytics no longer being supported from July 1, 2023.

I found a solution using the Google Track Manager and GA4 which will track clicks within any area of an iframe, regardless of where exactly. I liked this solution since one doesn't need to install a dedicated GTM container for the iframe, or to contact the iframe third party developer to provide data back to the caller. It is pretty straightforward.

So I followed the steps exactly as explained in this link:

https://ezsegment.com/tracking-iframe-interactions-using-gtm/

and it worked for me.

Comment: I used this answer to simply track if an iframe was interacted with. In our case it was a podcast player. Since all we wanted was a true/fasle - are people interacting with the player, this answer worked perfectly and did not require any special configuration from other parties.