# Tracking Iframe Clicks in Google Analytics

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

a similar question has already been asked, but I didn't quite get the answer I was hoping for. So maybe one of you can clear things up a bit for me:

I work for a travel company and we offer our affiliate partners the possibility to integrate our booking mask via iframe on their websites.

I recently set up a second booking site and embedded our own affiliate iframe. The result, however, is that I can no longer see how many clicks I generated via the iframe. Before, I used to have just a link to our company website and I could easily see the traffic through Channels>Acquisitions>Referral.

This is how the iframe looks like: `<iframe src="https://www.website123.com/partner_iframe_landing.php?partner_ID=z7Yb2b5DncB9TTgk&amp;ort_ab=000015&amp;ort_an=003600" width="550" height="470" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless=""></iframe>`

Basically I don't care whether I am tracking the clicks through our company's GA account or through the new website's account as long as I can get the data, I'm fine with it.

Is there any simple way to track this?

Looking forward to your replies

Christina

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Track Clicks in an IFrame with Google Analytics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966960/how-to-track-clicks-in-an-iframe-with-google-analytics)

Comment: Except that I have access to both websites.