# Analytics track Youtube iframe on my website

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, youtube

I'm trying to track the views of a video that is displayed in my website. To show the video i use an iframe:

```
<iframe width="640" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Videoid?autoplay=1" style="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now i have to add something like:

```
&utm_source=website&utm_medium=click&utm_campaign=campName
```

I have already attached this tail url to other object in my page that i wanna track (facebook link,download link,ecc...) and it works.So i have tried this solution, but it doesn't works:

```
<iframe width="640" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VideoId?autoplay=1&utm_source=website&utm_medium=click&utm_campaign=campName" style="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What's the difference? Only the iframe nature or Youtube  wants a call made in another way? I have read something on stackOverflow and google, the solution seems to be an migration to youTube api logic, but if possible i wanna use the iframe. There's another way to include the tail url :

```
&utm_source=website&utm_medium=click&utm_campaign=campName
```

in an Iframe?

Comment: adding &utm_source=website&utm_medium=click&utm_campaign=campName at the end of a url will enable tracking on that website.  so you just sent tracking to youtube.com.  I am sure there marketing people will applicate that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Track Clicks in an IFrame with Google Analytics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966960/how-to-track-clicks-in-an-iframe-with-google-analytics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by insert an onclick event on the button that launch the video:

```
onclick="_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘extlink’, ‘click’, ‘Showvideo’]);"
```

Comment: What HTML element received this `onclick`? I bet not on the iFrame, so then how do you really know the video was played?